# Indexing when multiple tables are involved

Tags: sql, sql-server

Our CRM system has tables like this

```
tablenameBase (entityid, basefield1, basefield2, basefield3)
tablenameExtensionBase (entityid, extfield1, extfield2, extfield3)
```

Then for each pair of tables it has a view such as

```
SELECT a.entityid, a.basefield1, a.basefield2, a.basefield3, 
b.extfield1, b.extfield2, b.extfield3
FROM tablenameBase a
LEFT JOIN tablenameExtensionBase b
ON a.entityid = b.entityid
```

You're supposed to then run queries directly on the view.

```
SELECT * FROM vw WHERE basefield1 LIKE '%@search%' OR extfield1 LIKE '%search%'
```

This is obviously a simple example but these queries on the views don't perform very well. I was looking at adding an index but can't add it to the view as it's not schema bound, and I can't change that.

Is it worth adding indexes to the underlying tables, would that be of any benefit?

Thanks

Comment: Probably not. Assuming `entityId` is the primary key for both tables, then the join condition is already indexed, so that's fine.  So then the problem becomes the conditions on `basefield1` and `extfield1`. Because you are doing full text-style searching on those fields, normal indexes won't help you. Maybe you need some type of full text indexing in this case.

Comment: LIKE with wildcard (%) at start (`LIKE '%search%'`) prevents query optimizer from using indexes.  as @sstan mentioned, you may want to build full text index and use it for searching. You should give it a try - full text search is very powerful.